# I want to build a real-time earthquake mapping on website,but I cant connect the api from USGS

Tags: html, kml

**This is API I used, but it can't show in the map**

I can't find the information how to get the data in the format of KML

```
  var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({

      url: 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1',
      format: new ol.format.KML({
        extractStyles: false
      })
    }),
    blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
    radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10)
  });
```

Comment: The URL in your code is the link for the USGS web page with API documentation. Have you tried it a URL that points directly to one of their KML files?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't tell a lot about the background.
I assume you're using a map library.

When I do this call in a Rest tool :

```
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/catalogs?format=kml
```

it works pretty well, returns a 200 status(good) and catalogs list in the asked format.

Are you sure:

- You made a GET request ? (POST will fail and lead to Forbidden access
  response)
- You tried to stick the parameters after the endpoint, like the given 
  example ?